# Variable values not visable when Stepping through Release in VS 2013 C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I've followed the following instructions on how to step through and debug an executable when compiled in release mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx

The problem I'm running into is that although I can step through the program, I can't view the value of variables, which making stepping fairly useless.

Any ideas as to what might cause the issue?

Comment: Debug in a Debug build.

Comment: The fact that the code you see and the code that is running is *not* the same due to optimizations also generally makes trying to debug a release build useless.

Comment: You can somewhat combat this by using the RelWithDebInfo configuration and also turning optimizations off. I have had to do that a few times when the Debug build worked but the release build failed and it was not easy to spot the bug / undefined behavior.

Comment: The problem is that in debug mode, the application is almost impossible to run because it is so much slower.

I think the issue is the memory checking and iterator checking.

Comment: Understood. In lung cancer research we have an application that segments the lungs. This application takes up to a few minutes in release build but days in debug build.

Comment: Any idea why the question got downvoted? Seems like a perfectly valid question as to why VS 2013 can step, but not view variables.

Comment: @drescherjm I think the biggest culpret is iterator checking and some memory checking. Do you use STD data structures a lot? I've found that deallocation can be over 100 times slower in debug mode, which doesnt have to do with the optimizer as much as some memory checking in debug mode.

Comment: In this case there was quite a bit of stl used with stacks ... and lots of allocations.

Comment: ***Seems like a perfectly valid question as to why VS 2013 can step, but not view variables.*** I did not downvote but I gave you basically all you can do. Turn off optimizations and use the RelWithDebInfo configuration.